# JFileChooser that will only select java supported image file formats

Tags: java, swing

I am going to develop a project where i only have to select the java supported image file formats for further image processing. Can anyone please suggest me that how to do this..

i already know about the following code that will select .bmp file formats..

```
    JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("bmp files", "bmp");
    fileOpen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    int ret = fileOpen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`getReaderFileSuffixes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFileSuffixes%28%29) method of the `javax.imageio.ImageIO` class to get an array of the available file extensions.

```
import javax.imageio.*;

...

JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();

// Get array of available formats
String[] suffices = ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes();

// Add a file filter for each one
for (int i = 0; i < suffices.length; i++) {
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(suffices[i] + " files", suffices[i]);
    fileOpen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
}

// Show dialog
int ret = fileOpen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. You want to create Filters for the supported formats. These can be retrieved from within the `JavaX.ImageIO` library.

This link describes how to find the readers and writers available: [Clicky](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/list-read-write-supported-image-formats/)

More information on what ImageIO can do can be found in the  [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)
or in the [Oracle ImageIO Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)